# Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=2-x^2$. Show $f((-1,1))$, $f([0,\infty))$ and $f^{-1}(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=2-x^2$. Show $f((-1,1))$, $f([0,\infty))$ and $f^{-1}(\mathbb{N})$

So I need to both find these images, and preimage and then justify my answers.

So for $f((-1,1))$

I know that $f(x)=2-x^2$ is a continuous function, I know that $f(0)=2$ is the max and that as $x\to \pm 1$, $f(x)\to 1$. Thus $f((-1,1))=(1,2]$. Since by IVT, the function will attain all points between $f(\pm 1)$ and $f(0)$.

> I believe the part I'm most unsure of is the use of Intermediate Value
>   Theorem because the statement of the theorem I have is:
>
> if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then if $u$ is a number such that
>   $\min{f(a),f(b)}<u<\max{f(a),f(b)}$ then there exists a $c\in(a,b)$
>   such that $f(c)=u$
>
> But in the first case I have open intervals, I could split the
>   interval $(-1,1)$ into $(-1,0]$ and $[0,1)$ but it still doesn't
>   exactly match the use of this theorem. Though it feels like the intuitive sense of the theorem is that a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ maps intervals to intervals.

For $f([0,\infty))$

I have $f(0)=2$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=-\infty$, thus $f([0,\infty))=(-\infty,2]$, I believe this is again should follow from IVT.

For $f^{-1}(\mathbb{N})$

I believe I simply have $\{0,-1,1,-2,2\}$
I don't think I have a great justification for this. I have $f(x)=n$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$, if $n=2-x^2$, then $x=\sqrt{2-n}$.

Thus $x\in \mathbb{R}$ if and only if $n\leq 2$, then $n=0,1,2$. So I simply computed the inverse and then used that to find the values for $x$.

Comment: Did you mean $\pm\sqrt{2}$ in the last one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $f((-1,1))$, what you wrote is OK. Still, if you want to match the IVT exactly, then you can note that $f([0,1])=[1,2]$ and $f([-1,0])=[1,2]$. Thus, $f([-1,1])=[1,2]$. However, $f(x)=1$ if and only if $x=\pm 1$. So excluding $x=\pm 1$ as inputs leads to excluding $1$ from the image. Thus, $f((-1,1))=(1,2]$.

For $f^{-1}(\mathbb{N})$, $x\in f^{-1}(\mathbb{N})$ means that $2-x^2$ is a natural number. $2-x^2\leq 2$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. So the only options are $2-x^2\in\{0,1,2\}$, and you simply have to solve the $3$ equations.